# ClickOnce and mageUI adding custom file folder problems

Tags: deployment, msbuild, clickonce, signing

What I do: Publishing .Net 3.5 application via VS, or msbuild (whatever), and now I need to insert to the published application separate directory (Modules - not added as a reference to the project - our project architecture does not allow this). So I'm copying the folder to published location then runs mageUI.exe select the application manifest and then the problems starts. As I press the populate button it's adding also hidden directory? So I remove the directory, after I want to save the manifest file I get the 
"Warning MSB3110: Assembly 'NAME.Shell.application.deploy' has mismatched identity 'NAME.Shell.application', expected file name: 'NAME.Shell.application.application'".

Did you have the same problems, according to http://smartclient.codeplex.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?DownloadId=5060 it should be easy as 1-2-3 but it's not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the irony side, I am currently updating the SCSF documentation for ClickOnce deployment for .NET 4.0, and now I know exactly what the problem it.

First, you want to publish to a disk location, not directly to the webserver. So do that, and then copy the dll's you want to add to the deployment into the version folder with the application manifest (.manifest). Rename them yourself -- just add .deploy on the end.

Bring up MageUI and open the application manifest in that folder, then uncheck the box that says "add .deploy to the file names". Click "populate".

Then remove the deployment manifest from the list; it's called something like appname.application. You don't want it to be included in the manifest's list of files.

Now you can save and sign the application manifest. Then without exiting mageUI, open the deployment manifest that is in the root folder (*NOT* the one in the version folder). Click on "Application Reference", then click Select Manifest. Dig down to the application manifest in the version folder that you just signed and select it. Then just save and sign the deployment manifest. It puts a relative path in there, so if you modify the .application file in the version folder, it won't work right when deployed.

Now take that .application file from the root folder and copy it into the version folder (replacing the one that's there) so you have the right copy for that version in case you need it later.

Now copy the whole shebang out to the webserver. it should work.

Comment: Thanks!!! Finally it's working as I expected. Now I need to do this via msbuild script:) Let's pray!!!:)

Comment: I know how to do it with Mage, but haven't messed around with msbuild. Good luck! :-)

Comment: this link also helped me:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsto/archive/2009/04/29/signing-and-re-signing-manifests-in-clickonce.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think you are saying you need to add a folder of stuff to your ClickOnce deployment? What exactly are you adding? You say modules -- are they going to be compiled in, or is it something else?

If you want to add files to the deployment you have already created, you need to use MageUI to edit the application manifest, which is called something like appname.exe.manifest. (The appname.application is actually called the deployment manifest, which is confusing but true.) After adding the files, you will need to re-sign the deployment manifest as well (assuming you signed it in the first place).

It would be easier just to add what you want included to your project and re-publish. Depending on what it is, you can set the build action to 'content' (jpegs, html, etc) or 'none' (dll's) and then set "copy to output directory" to true, and it will include it in your deployment.

I'm not sure exactly what you are including. Give me more info, and I can provide more specific help.

RobinDotNet