# Getting error on creating deployment using MageUI

Tags: c#, winforms, oneclick

I need to change a database configuration in app.config.exe in a one click application. 
I looked up several information in creating the deployment in MageUI. 
http://danielbergsten.wordpress.com/2010/12/21/change-application-configuration-in-an-already-published-clickonce-app/
http://community.discountasp.net/showthread.php?t=14370
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7082410/clickonce-setup-exe-fails-but-the-application-file-works-fine-when-using-a-wind

I found this link to seem the most direct but I did not get rid of my error from following this link either.
[ClickOnce and mageUI adding custom file folder problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2514944/clickonce-and-mageui-adding-custom-file-folder-problems).
Actually this is exactly what I am looking for in a solution except the solution in the link given did not work for me.

I)
I tried several combinations to see if it would work.
1) sign manifest in application version folder . (.manfest file)
2) sign application deployment in root folder and using newly signed manifest (.application)
3) copy it over to application version.

II)
1) sign manifest in application version folder . (.manfest file)
2) sign application deployment using new manifest.
3) copy application deployment to application version and then sign it again using new manifest in application folder.

III)
1) sign manifest and check add .deploy.
2) sign application deployment in root folder.
3) copy application deployment to application folder.

I am not getting any luck in resolving the error I am getting.
The error I get is when I try running the one application from DEV web server environment is. I get a 404 error and the config file is not found.
If I publish the application from VS it works good.
The issue is I need to change only a production database value and I do not want to publish from VS2010 and Ijust want to use the .exe and config directly from production  and just change the config and resign everything using the MageUI. I am trying to do the resign on DEV environment to see if the resigning works when deployed to DEV so I could do the same steps on production. DEV deployment after resigning FAILS. 
Please do not suggest mage becuase I am just not able to run mage as a command line though I would like to know how I can do it. I tried that and I get mage not found but MageUI works good.
I am not sure what step I am missing here. 
Here is the full error stack trace when I try opening this one click application link using the webserver where I deployed it to.

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
    Windows             : 6.1.7601.65536 (Win32NT)
    Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.17929
    System.Deployment.dll       : 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    clr.dll             : 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    dfdll.dll           : 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    dfshim.dll          : 4.0.41209.0 (Main.041209-0000)

SOURCES
    Deployment url          : http://dev/pfs/priority/DEV/PriorityWinApp-DEV.application
                        Server      : Microsoft-IIS/7.5
                        X-Powered-By    : ASP.NET
    Application url         : http://dev/pfs/priority/DEV/Application%20Files/PriorityWinApp-DEV_1_0_3_128/PriorityWinApp-DEV.exe.manifest
                        Server      : Microsoft-IIS/7.5
                        X-Powered-By    : ASP.NET

IDENTITIES
    Deployment Identity     : PriorityWinApp-DEV.application, Version=1.0.3.128, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2c3d7f3ec71aa887, processorArchitecture=msil
    Application Identity        : PriorityWinApp-DEV.exe, Version=1.0.3.128, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2c3d7f3ec71aa887, processorArchitecture=msil, type=win32

APPLICATION SUMMARY
    * Online only application.
    * Trust url parameter is set.
ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of http://dev/pfs/priority/DEV/PriorityWinApp-DEV.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Downloading http://dev/pfs/priority/DEV/Application Files/PriorityWinApp-DEV_1_0_3_128/PriorityWinApp-DEV.exe.config did not succeed.
        + The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    * [5/26/2013 12:22:07 PM] : Activation of http://dev/pfs/priority/DEV/PriorityWinApp-DEV.application has started.
    * [5/26/2013 12:22:07 PM] : Processing of deployment manifest has successfully completed.
    * [5/26/2013 12:22:07 PM] : Installation of the application has started.
    * [5/26/2013 12:22:07 PM] : Processing of application manifest has successfully completed.
    * [5/26/2013 12:22:09 PM] : Found compatible runtime version 4.0.30319.
    * [5/26/2013 12:22:09 PM] : Request of trust and detection of platform is complete.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [5/26/2013 12:22:10 PM] System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentDownloadException (Unknown subtype)
        - Downloading http://dev/pfs/priority/DEV/Application Files/PriorityWinApp-DEV_1_0_3_128/PriorityWinApp-DEV.exe.config did not succeed.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadAllFiles()
            at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.Download(SubscriptionState subState)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDependencies(SubscriptionState subState, AssemblyManifest deployManifest, AssemblyManifest appManifest, Uri sourceUriBase, String targetDirectory, String group, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId, TempDirectory& downloadTemp)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.Net.WebException
        - The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
        - Source: System
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    No transaction information is available.
```